# Accessing chrome.storage.sync

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that has 30 checkboxes on the options page. I am trying to save which checkboxes are checked using

```
var jsonfile={};
document.getElementById("teamdiv").addEventListener('change',function(e){
    jsonfile[e.target.id+""]=true;
    storeValue(jsonfile);
});
```

How can I retrieve all the values inside the jsonfile inside a different javascript file without having a seperate

```
chrome.storage.sync.get()
```

statement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for `Object.keys(jsonfile)`?

Comment: Well, jsonfile is a variable in my options javascript page, but I need to access the storage in the popup's javascript page. How can I do this?

Comment: That seems somewhat different from the question you ask in your post. You might want to [edit] your question to explain that you want to access the object from a different page. My guess is that you want [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to pass `jsonfile` to a different script context.

Answer (score 0):

Use Background Script in extension [backgoundscript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) to communicate between pages

```
      {
        "name": "My extension",
         ...
        "background": {
           "scripts": ["background.js"]
         },
         ...
      }
```